# Genymotion 2.7 resizing (scalable)

Tags: android, resize, genymotion, scalable

I have updated Genymotion to 2.7.2 and now I have problem to up-scale emulator window.

I have virtual device 320x480 and when I enlarge the emulator window, virtual device size remain the same (too small on my laptop). With previous version virtual device screen was scalable. Is there any new settings or its bug, or its new feature ? 
(I have updated Virtual Box too but it didn't resolve the issue)

Comment: I downgrade to 2.6 and its scalable again.

Comment: Yeah this is enough to make me switch to the built in emulator :( Can't really see an obvious fix.